# How to make angular material sidenav appear over main view?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an angular material sidenav, when I click menu icon, a sidenav opened on the left side but it pushes the main view but if I click the menu button it should open above the main view.

[image]

[image]

I have added pictures of what I want it to look like. How can i do this?

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-example-clhoqp?file=main.ts)

Answer (score 1):

You can change `mode` to `over` as:

```
<mat-drawer-container>
    <mat-drawer #snav [mode]="'over'"> <=== change it here
        ...
    </mat-drawer>

    <mat-drawer-content>
        ...
    </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

**Update 1:**

You can use `mat-sidenav` for your desired output. Don't forget to check CSS.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-example-3upd1e) you can find code.

Comment: i want to make sidenav above header also .if i add over only it s coming over the body not in header

Comment: you can follow example provided by Angular here: https://stackblitz.com/angular/xeeqddpejgy?file=app%2Fsidenav-disable-close-example.ts That's what you want I guess.

Comment: @Anushuman Jaiswal i don't want backdrop and all i want sidenav should come over body and header (full page) can you help me out pls

Comment: @coco I have updated answer added updated stackblitz.

Comment: its not working properly when i click menu icon you can see some animaton going left to rigth(scrol bar coming right end of the page )

Comment: bro still same issue

Comment: @coco it's not same. try to run in incognito.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sidenav-example-3upd1e .can you check the given link scrol bar coming at the right hand side of the page .can you pls take a look

Comment: that could be fixed from CSS, anyway fixed it. Check it now.

Comment: bro check 2nd image how can i do this

Comment: i need scrolling also can you pls help me out